TINA-TI "Irregular Circiut" Error of HPF Simulation
I'm trying to design a 2nd order fully differential MFB high pass filter with 1Hz cutoff frequency. I used FilterPro to design the needed  filter then tried to simulate it on TINA-TI with THS4551 differential amplifier.
I want to use this filter to eliminate lower frequency of EEG signal sample.
However, TINA-TI gives me "Irregular Circuit" error, and I could not understand what the problem was. I am quite new at electronics so guess I am missing some points here.
(There is a sample of EEG as .wav format in VG1)




Why are the Vout... shorted?

@Antonio51 Vout1 and Vout2 are not actually shorted, i guess it is a bit hard to see in the pictures. can you explain if i misunderstand you ?

@blakereeves The top schematic shows a shorted output and the graph corner freq is at 10 Hz, not 1 Hz as shown in the text. Try placing 10meg resistors in the bottom schematic from both terminals of VG1 (nodes 9 & 10) to ground. See if this helps.

@qrk I placed 10Meg resistor to the node 9, also placed ground to the tip of the node 10 and 10Meg between node 10 and ground as you said. However, it says irregular circuit on node 6 (C7) in the bottom schematic.
I am trying to see the AC transfer characteristic of the circuit.
